# Spring Hibernate inserting parent along with children

Tags: spring, hibernate

My program requirement is to add a new parent to the database along with the children. So far I have this method in the parent class:

```
  @Transient
public void addLecturer(Lecturer lecturer) {
    if(lecturers == null) {
        lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
        }
    lecturer.setChecker(this);

    this.lecturers.add(lecturer);
 }
```

Then a save parent in my parent dao:

```
    @Override
public void addChecker(Lecturer checker) {
      Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

      session.save(checker);

     }
```

My controller:

```
     @RequestMapping(value="/matching_page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView get(@ModelAttribute("checker") Lecturer checker, BindingResult 

  result) { 
ArrayList<String> lecturers = new ArrayList<String>();   
    lecturers.add("Somma");
    lecturers.add("Trina");
    lecturers.add("Adam");
    lecturers.add("Eve");

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> model = new HashMap<String 

  ArrayList<String>>(); 
     model.put("lecturerList", lecturers); 
   return new ModelAndView("matching_page", "model", model);

}

  @RequestMapping(value="/matching_page", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView hello(@ModelAttribute("checker") Lecturer checker, 

   BindingResult result) { 
    lecturerService.addChecker(checker);

    return new ModelAndView ("redirect:/admin");
}
```

The jsp form:

```
     <c:url var="saveUrl" value="/matching_page" />
<form:form modelAttribute="checker" method="POST" action="${saveUrl}">

<td>Checker </td>
<tr>
<td><form:hidden path="lecturerId" value="" /></td>
</tr>

  <tr>
   <td><form:label path="name">Checker Name:</form:label></td>
   <td><form:input path="name"/></td>

  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
   <td><form:input path="email"/></td>

  </tr>
   <td>Lecturers</td>
   <td>
      <form:select path="name" multiple="true">
        <form:option value="0" >Select </form:option>
            <form:options items="${model.lecturerList}" />

      </form:select>
  </td>

  <div id="lower">
<input  type="submit" value="Save Selection" class="button"/>
</div>
   </form:form>
```

My database:

```
  CREATE TABLE `lecturers` (
 `lecturer_id` BIGINT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `checker_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lecturer_id`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`checker_id`) REFERENCES `lecturers` (`lecturer_id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My model

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "lecturers")
   @Component
   public class Lecturer implements Serializable{

   @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   @JoinColumn(name="checker_id")
   private Lecturer checker;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="checker", orphanRemoval=true)
   private List<Lecturer> lecturers = new ArrayList<Lecturer>();
   }
```

The form has a parent object (checker) bound to it and I want to add one or more children selected from the select list and saved.

The save works but but it saves all new objects as children and doesn't save the checker parent separately with a checker id. I'm not sure what the problem is and would like to know.

Comment: You say it saves all the new objects as children...but how can it do this (which implies they have a parent thus a value for `checker_id`) when the parent (checker) isn't also saved?

Answer (score 0):

Post your model definitions.  My guess is that your problem is rising from your strange attempt to relate the "Parent" with its "Children."

With hibernate, you only *have* to do one side, and hibernate will take care of the other side.  As an example:

```
public class MyObject {
    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "myColumnName")
    private MyObject parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<MyObject> children;

    public void addChild(MyObject child) {
        children.add(child);
    }

    public void removeChild(MyObject child) {
        children.remove(child);
    }

    // Other Accessors
}
```

Using it...

```
public MyObject create(MyObject parent) {
    // Obtain a collection of MyObject that you would like to associate as "parent's" children
    for (MyObject curObject : myListOfObjects)
        parent.addChild(curObject);
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(parent);
}
```

I don't actually *have* to set each child's `parent` since Hibernate is going to take care of that for me.  All I need to do is put each child into the parent's collection of children.  This act alone is sufficient to cause an insert to occur if taken on an entity that is both non-transient *and* attached.

```
@Transactional
public void update(parentId,child) {
    myDaoClass.readById(parentId).addChild(child);
    // When the current transaction ends, hibernate will issue a commit to persist the
    // child that we added (created) here.  No need to call session.persist(...) on it.
    // Assuming no exceptions are thrown, of course.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm going through your suggestions now. In the meanwhile I have edited my question to add the model. It's one class.

Comment: The model looks good.  I trust you have an id column and column annotations for the other data (email, name, etc) and just snipped them out for brevity?